# Nested RelativeLayouts to half parent width?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

When I add this, the buttons I add programatically to the RelativeLayouts don't show up in the layouts. But when I change the width from 0 to fill parent, they overlap. How can I make each RelativeLayout take up half the width of the LinearLayout?

```
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/svButtons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="175dp" >

     <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linlayColumns"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rellayLeftColumn"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
         </RelativeLayout>

         <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rellayRightColumn"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
      </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout> 

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split your `RelativeLayouts` horizontally, your `LinearLayout` orientation should be set to `horizontal` :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linlayColumns"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    ... >
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you, that solved it! Such a simple overlooked mistake.